# Display UIAlertView before opening phone.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, nsurl, phone-number

I have a view on map with a button and a label on the button.
On the label i have phone number that comes from a plist.
The variable of the phone number in the plist called "storePhone" and i implemented it in this way:

```
text4.text = myAnn.storePhone;
```

I made this method for pressing the button and opening the phone.app for dialing the number.
Everything works great but i want a UIViewAlert to say to the user something like:"your going to dial this number, are you sure?" before the phone.app is open.

How can i do that?

This is my button methode:

```
-(IBAction)callToStore
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", text4.text]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did it.
This is how you do it:

```
- (IBAction)moreInfoViewAlert:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"חיוג לסניף"
                                                  message:@"הנך עומד/ת לבצע חיוג, האם את/ה בטוח?"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"ביטול"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"חיוג", nil];
    [message show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"חיוג"])
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", text4.text]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```

Attach the IBAction method to your button and you're good to go.