# Open a link when alert ok button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I get this alert code when I press a button it opens a message:

```
- (void)patchButtonPressed
{
UIAlertView *patchAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"After clicking `OK` you will be redirected to Cydia" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[patchAlert show];
[patchAlert release];
```

But I want that after clicking OK, it redirects to an URL (`cydia://package/mypackage`).

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478198/display-uialertview-before-opening-phone-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need `pathAlert.delegate = self`.  You've already set the delegate in the `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:` method call.

In your `.h` file, you need to do this:

```
@interface YourViewControllerName : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

And in the `.m` file add this method:

```
- alertView:(id)alert didDismissWithButton:(int)index {
    [[UIpplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"foo"];    
}
```

---

Alternatively, and possibly better might be to give the user the option of "Ok" to be redirected or "Cancel" to not navigate to that page.  In which case, you need to create the alert as such:

```
UIAlertView *patchAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
              message:@"After clicking `OK` you will be redirected to Cydia" 
             delegate:self 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
    otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
```

Then, you can modify the handle method as such:

```
- alertView:(id)alert didDismissWithButton:(int)index {
    if(index == 1) {
        [[UIpplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"foo"];
    }  
}
```

Now the `URL` is only opened if they click "OK", otherwise nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

set the delegate of the alertView and in the didDismiss method open the url

```
UIAlertView *patchAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"After clicking `OK` you will be redirected to Cydia" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
pathAlert.delegate = self;
[patchAlert show];
[patchAlert release];
```

...

```
- alertView:(id)alert didDismissWithButton:(int)index {
    [[UIpplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"BLA"];    
}
```

Comment: written inline. sloppy and incorrect but shows what you have to do